# Проблема с "деревом" на vue.js

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

Окей, это не совсем дерево, а просто что-то вроде раскрывающегося списка. Немного застряла - не знаю, как сделать так, чтобы когда я нажимаю на конкретный заголовок "раскрывался" только этот заголовок, а не все заголовки на странице.
Уверена, что есть более изящный способ, чем писать к каждому пункту другую переменную, но пока что этот способ не нашла. Очень нужна помощь, спасибо!

```js
< script >
  import Support from '../components/Support'
export default {
  name: 'Help',
  components: {
    Support
  },
  data() {
    return {
      isActive: true,
      main_question: 'ОБЩИЕ ВОПРОСЫ',
      sub_question: 'Как быстро происходит обмен?',
      answer: 'Большинство обменов на нашем сервисе автоматические. Они происходят в течений 1-й минуты после оплаты заявки. В тех случаях когда обмен происходит в полу-автоматическом режиме (перед обменом Вы увидите предупреждение об этом: скорость выполнения заявки зависит от степени загруженности оператора и обычно составляет 2-20 минут.',
      show: true,
      small: true
    }
  },
  methods: {
    changeStatus: function() {
      this.isActive = !this.isActive
    }
  }
}

<
/script>
```

```css
.trans_border_m_20 {
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.answers_bl {
  margin-top: 35px;
  .answer_item_title_main {
    font-family: "SFUIDisplay-Medium", sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: $greyD3;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    border-top: 1px solid $greyL;
    padding: 15px 0 12px 0px;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  .answer_item_title_main.disabled {
    &:last-child {
      border-bottom: 1px solid $greyL;
    }
  }
  .answer_item_title_main.active {
    border-bottom: 1px solid $greyL;
    .ico_trigger {
      transform: rotate(180deg);
      transition: -webkit-transform .2s ease;
      transition: transform .2s ease;
      transition: transform .2s ease, -webkit-transform .2s ease;
    }
  }
  .answer_item_main .answer_item:last-child .answer_item_title_minor.active+.answer_item_txt {
    border-bottom: none;
  }
  .ico_trigger {
    margin-right: 17px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
  }
  .answer_item_title_minor.active+.answer_item_txt {
    border-bottom: 1px solid $greyL;
  }
  .answer_item {
    padding-left: 70px;
    .answer_item_title_minor,
    .trigger_symbol {
      color: $blueD;
      font-family: "SFUIDisplay-Medium", sans-serif;
      font-size: 16px;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    .answer_item_title_minor {
      padding: 14px 0 11px 0px;
      display: block;
      border-bottom: 1px solid $greyL;
    }
    .answer_item {
      .answer_item_title_minor.disabled {
        &:last-child {
          border-bottom: none;
        }
      }
    }
    .answer_item_title_minor.active {
      border: none;
      .trigger_symbol {
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: middle;
        border: none;
        transform: rotate(90deg);
        transition: -webkit-transform .2s ease;
        transition: transform .2s ease;
        transition: transform .2s ease, -webkit-transform .2s ease;
      }
    }
    .trigger_symbol {
      display: inline-block;
      margin-left: 8px;
    }
    .txt_container {
      font-family: "SFNS-display-thin", sans-serif;
      font-size: 14px;
      color: $greyD3;
      text-align: justify;
      padding: 12px 0 25px 0;
    }
    .txt_container.active {
      border-bottom: 1px solid $greyL;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="top_bl trans_border trans_border_m_20">
      <h1 class="big_title">Помощь по работе с сервисом</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="answers_bl main_center_bl ">
      <div class="answer_item_main">
        <div @click="show = !show" class="answer_item_title_main" v-on:click="changeStatus" v-bind:class="{ active: isActive }"><span class="ico_trigger"></span>{{main_question}}</div>
        <div v-if="show" class="answer_item">
          <div @click="small = !small" class="answer_item_title_minor" v-on:click="changeStatus" v-bind:class="{ active: isActive }">{{sub_question}}<span class="trigger_symbol">></span></div>
          <div v-if="small" class="answer_item_txt">
            <p class="txt_container">{{answer}}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div v-if="show" class="answer_item">
          <div @click="small = !small" class="answer_item_title_minor" v-on:click="changeStatus" v-bind:class="{ active: isActive }">{{sub_question}}<span class="trigger_symbol">></span></div>
          <div v-if="small" class="answer_item_txt">
            <p class="txt_container">{{answer}}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div v-if="show"  class="answer_item">
          <div  @click="small = !small" class="answer_item_title_minor" v-on:click="changeStatus" v-bind:class="{ active: isActive }">{{sub_question}}<span class="trigger_symbol">></span></div>
          <div v-if="small" class="answer_item_txt">
            <p class="txt_container">{{answer}}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="answer_item_main">
        <div @click="show = !show" class="answer_item_title_main" v-on:click="changeStatus" v-bind:class="{ active: isActive }"><span class="ico_trigger"></span>{{main_question}}</div>
        <div v-if="show" class="answer_item">
          <div @click="small = !small" class="answer_item_title_minor" v-on:click="changeStatus" v-bind:class="{ active: isActive }">{{sub_question}}<span class="trigger_symbol">></span></div>
          <div v-if="small" class="answer_item_txt">
            <p class="txt_container">{{answer}}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я бы  все "answer_item" выводил `v-for` что бы не писать такое количество v-on:click и прочего в обработке каждого элемента, легче написать 1 раз и прогнать циклом , создать отдельный массив обьектов , а там легче было бы их раскрывать из-за `(item,index)` ,  дать каждому из внутренних обьектов `flag` "show", и менять его с помощью того же `index` в `v-for` .